# Load groovy classes/scripts dynamically without compilation?

Tags: groovy, classloader

I have a set of groovy scripts in package hierarchy. I have 1 main script, from which I want to call others. For example I have these scripts (with public classes/interfaces of the same name in them):

```
package.MainScript
package.MyInterface;

package.utils.MyInterfaceImpl1 //implements MyInterface
package.utils.MyInterfaceImpl2 //implements MyInterface
```

Is there a way to call one script from the other **without knowing called class name at compile time**? I mean to do something like dynamic class loading  like:

```
class MainScript {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      MyInterface instance = Class.forName("package.utils.Util1");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! Groovy is a dynamic language. You can [create class instance dynamically](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2010/06/groovy-goodness-create-class-instance.html).

```
package.MyInterface
class MyInterfaceImpl1 {
    def greet() {
        "Hello"
    }    
}

package.MyInterface
class MyInterfaceImpl2 {
    def greet() {
        "Hi!"
    }   
}

def name = 'MyInterfaceImpl1' // Choose whatever you want at runtime
def className = Class.forName("MyInterface.$name")
def instance = className.newInstance()
assert instance.greet() == 'Hello'
```

Comment: The problem is, that to load the class using Class.forName you have to have this class compiled, somewhere on your classpath. What I need to do is to load it without having to compile. When I try what you propose, I get ClassNotFoundException :(

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Compiling Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiling+Groovy). See the section Dynamically using Groovy inside Java applications.

Comment: Yes, that's it - see Arturo's comment for answer to my question. Thanks Arturo.

Comment: Looks like that link is not longer active. This is the new location: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#groovyclassloader